# Using Cython extension module to wrap std::vector - How do I program __setitem__() method?

Tags: cython

This seems like a question that should have an obvious answer, but for some reason I can't find any examples online.

I am wrapping a vector of C++ objects in a Python class using Cython.  I also have a Cython wrapper for the C++ class already coded.  I can get several methods such as `__len__()`, `__getitem__()`, and `resize()` to work properly, but the `__setitem__()` method is giving me problems.

For simplicity, I coded a small example using a vector of `int`s.  I figure if I can get this code to work, then I can build on that to get the solution for my C++ class as well.

`MyPyModule.pyx`

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref

cdef class MyArray:
    cdef vector[int]* thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new vector[int]()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def __len__(self):
        return self.thisptr.size()

    def __getitem__(self, size_t key):
        return self.thisptr.at(key)

    def resize(self, size_t newsize):
        self.thisptr.resize(newsize)

    def __setitem__(self, size_t key, int value):
        # Attempt 1:
        # self.thisptr.at(key) = value

        # Attempt 2:
        # cdef int* itemptr = &(self.thisptr.at(key))
        # itemptr[0] = value

        # Attempt 3:
        # (self.thisptr)[key] = value

        # Attempt 4:
        self[key] = value
```

When I tried to cythonize using Attempt 1, I got the error `Cannot assign to or delete this`.  When I tried Attempt 2, the `.cpp` file was created, but the compiler complained that:

```
error: cannot convert ‘__Pyx_FakeReference<int>*’ to ‘int*’ in assignment
   __pyx_v_itemptr = (&__pyx_t_1);
```

On Attempt 3, Cython would not build the file because `Cannot assign type 'int' to 'vector[int]'`.  (When I tried this style with the C++ object instead of `int`, it complained because I had a reference as a left-value.)  Attempt 4 compiles, but when I try to use it, I get a segfault.

Cython [docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#c-left-values) say that returning a reference as a left-value is not supported, which is fine -- but how do I get around it so that I can assign a new value to one of my vector elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to access the vector through a pointer,

```
def __setitem__(self, size_t key, int value):
    deref(self.thisptr)[key] = value
    # or
    # self.thisptr[0][key] = value
```

Cython translates those two cases as follows:

```
Python: deref(self.thisptr)[key] = value
C++:    ((*__pyx_v_self->thisptr)[__pyx_v_key]) = __pyx_v_value;

Python: self.thisptr[0][key] = value
C++:    ((__pyx_v_self->thisptr[0])[__pyx_v_key]) = __pyx_v_value;
```

which are equivalent i.e. access the same vector object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to handle a pointer from Cython code, you can let Cython itself do it for you:

```
cdef class MyArray:
    cdef vector[int] thisptr

    def __len__(self):
        return self.thisptr.size()

    def __getitem__(self, size_t key):
        return self.thisptr[key]

    def __setitem__(self, size_t key, int value):
        self.thisptr[key] = value

    def resize(self, size_t newsize):
        self.thisptr.resize(newsize)
```

Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: Your approach does work, but I have to work with the pointer because in most cases, I will be creating the object in C++ and wrapping it for use in Python.  Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Comment: Then I think this link can help: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#add-public-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I have already accepted J.J. Hakala's answer (many thanks!).  I tweaked that method to include an out-of-bounds check, since it uses the `[]` operator instead of the `at()` method:

```
cdef class MyArray:
    (....)
    def __setitem__(self, size_t key, int value):
        if key < self.thisptr.size():
            deref(self.thisptr)[key] = value
        else:
            raise IndexError("Index is out of range.")
```